# change Mysql current_timestamp default value

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, timestamp

I have a field in a MySQL database with default value as `current_timestamp`

and i wish to insert value as follows:

e.g. `2014-01-25 03:53:14` to `2014-01-25 00:00:00`

How can i do this?

Any suggestion or idea would be great help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you should do is change the type of your field to `DATE` type.  Then create a trigger to SET NEW.field = `CURDATE()`.
Here's an example in [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ad17/1/0)

```
CREATE TRIGGER default_my_timestamp BEFORE INSERT ON yourTable
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.timestamp = CURDATE();
```